# Monitor HDDs on all servers

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, windows-server-2008, monitoring

Is it possible to monitor all servers and all hdds on all servers in our network from a central location?  For example, does a utility or application exist which I can install on my own desktop, which will show me the hdd space on all servers listed.

If at all possible, it would be even better if this utility can send out alerts/messages/emails when a servers hdd is critically slow on space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend Spiceworks. http://www.spiceworks.com/
It will do all of that and more.

Comment: Will I have to install this on all servers, or just the desktop from where it will monitor everything?

Comment: You would just install it on one machine, preferably a server (but it doesn't really matter), then you can access it from anywhere via a web browser, for example on your workstation. It will teach out to your servers to grab the info that you need.